# Run Twitter and Facebook Share Button Code After ListCtrl Update

Tags: javascript, facebook, angularjs, twitter

I'm building a website where I need to display Facebook like/ share buttons and a twitter share button on several elements in a list. Basically I have a list of events that are loaded asynchronously using an an angular controller and ng-repeat.

The problem I am encountering is that twitter and Facebook buttons require a js widget now and some js code needs to be executed to make the buttons display. This would be fine if the events were rendered server side, but they are instead done so using angular, and I need to have that js code executed after the events are rendered.

Essentially, my question is: how could I run some code each time after an ng-repeat is rendered in angular?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using directives, basically just added this to my javascript:

```
myApp.directive('afterEventsLoadedDirective', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last){
            // handle events here
        }
    };
});
```