# Link facebook share button to FB.ui()

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working with Facebook website integration and what to show a customized Facebook share dialog when clicking the Facebook delivered [share button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button/).

So i basically want a Facebook share button to call a JavaScript invocing the FB.ui() onclick instead of showing the stock dialog.

Is this possible?

[Feed and share Dialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

Comment: No, the Share dialog can currently not be invoked via FB.ui. Either show the URL version of it in a popup, or use the Feed dialog instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question also have make by other before this.. check it [Run Twitter and Facebook Share Button Code After ListCtrl Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960251/run-twitter-and-facebook-share-button-code-after-listctrl-update)

Comment: Thank you i'll look in to them